# Android Portrait to Landcape Slider & ImageView not responsive

Tags: android-layout

[My Portrait View is looks Fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEYQQ.jpg)
[My Landscape View alignment is collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPHqh.jpg)

this is my code of activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/img_slideshow_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/img_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/indicator"
            android:background="@color/PrimaryColor"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#ededed" />



    </RelativeLayout>
        <View android:id="@+id/div_a"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/img_slideshow_layout"
            android:background="@color/view_divider_color" />

        <View android:id="@+id/div_b"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/div_a"
            android:background="@color/view_divider_color_2" />

        <com.studiobluelime.utils.CirclePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>





    <!--<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ProgressBar
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:indeterminate="true" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/card_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>-->

  <!--  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/card_recycler_view_new"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>-->


</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/shop_online"
        android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
        android:id="@+id/shop_online"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/nandme"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="320dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:id="@+id/nandme"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/storelocation"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="258dp"
        android:id="@+id/storelocation"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/promotins"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/promotins"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginTop="240dp"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="157dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/PrimaryDarkColor"

    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/ripple"

    app:menu="@menu/navigation_items" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I wrote this code in four layouts: layout/activity_main.xml,layout-small/ activity_main.xml, layout-large/activity_main.xml, layout-xlarge/activity_main.xml but it did not change. I have attached a screen shot here. Please click the above name  "My Portrait View is looks Fine My Landscape View alignment is collapsed"

Comment: Pls anyone help me

Comment: You say that you have four layout files, but only one is posted. Are the contents of each layout file the same? If so, that is your problem - each layout file need to be modified to accommodate the targeted screen size/orientation. If the file contents aren't the same, posting the XML that works along with the XML that doesn't will assist someone in posting an answer.

Comment: thanks for  your suggestion cheticamp, i am  a beginner of  an android so i need more support to solve  this problem, any one pls help me